# Why is my file closing and causing "I/O operation on closed file" error on line 51?

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python and have been trying to write a "To-Do List" program over the past few days. Today I was working on a delete function for removing tasks from the list but I have been getting this error on line 51 where it says "f.write(line)" and I'm not sure why. The "integer.txt" is a text file that just starts at one and stores the next value on the list and "TodoData.txt" stores the actual data. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I realize this code is not very eloquent...

````
import csv
import pandas as pd

exit = False
hasOpened = False

rowNum = 1
with open('integer.txt', 'r') as f:
  a = f.read()
  b = list(a)
  rowNum = int(b[0])

print(" To-Do List")

while exit is False:
  entry = input("What would you like to do?\n a) add\n d) delete\n e) edit\n r) read\n q) quit\n\n")

  if entry is 'a':
    #this will add an item to the list
    with open('TodoData.txt', 'a') as data:
      csv_writer = csv.writer(data)
      csv_writer.writerow([rowNum, input('What would you like to add?\n\n')])
    print("successfully added!\n")
    rowNum += 1
    with open('integer.txt', 'w') as count:
      csv_writer = csv.writer(count)
      csv_writer.writerow([rowNum])
  elif entry is 'd':
    #this will delete an item from the list
    with open('TodoData.txt','r') as data:
      csv_reader = csv.reader(data)
      print(data.read())
    deletionKey = input('Which number would you like to delete?\n')
    deletionNum = int(deletionKey)
    if deletionNum <= rowNum and deletionNum > 0:
      with open("TodoData.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
      with open("TodoData.txt", "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
          if line[0] != deletionKey:
            value = line[0]
            NWvalue = value.strip()
            NWvalue = int(NWvalue)
            if NWvalue > deletionNum:
              oldNum = NWvalue
              oldNumStr = str(oldNum)
              newNum = NWvalue - 1
              newNumStr = str(newNum)
              d = line.lstrip(oldNumStr)
              line = newNumStr + d
              f.write(line)
              with open("integer.txt", "r") as f:
                position = f.readline()
                position = int(position) - 1
                position = str(position)
              with open("integer.txt", "w") as f:
                f.write(position)
            else:
              f.write(line)
    else:
      print('Please enter a valid list number.')
  elif entry is 'e':
    #this will edit an item on the list
    print("edit")
  elif entry is 'r':
    #this will read the to-do list
    with open('TodoData.txt','r') as data:
      csv_reader = csv.reader(data)
      print(data.read())
  elif entry is 'q':
    break
  else:
    print('Please enter a valid value. ')```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you nest `with open(...) as f:` you lose the local scope of the first `f`. Notice this will throw an error:

```py
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
        pass
    f.write("")
```

outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    f.write("")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Also, a side note: You can open a file with both [`read` and `write` privileges](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), but make sure to read the docs for reference on the file pointer:

```
lines = ["", ""]
with open("test.txt", "r+") as f:
    f.read()
    f.write("")
```

Comment: Thanks @Felipe, I appreciate it!

Comment: Yup, not a problem! Glad it helped :)